# Fully qualified domain name (FQDN) for services in Kubernetes not working? DNS-1035

Tags: kubernetes

I am following this [concept guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) on the kubernetes docs to connect to a service in a different namespace using the fully qualified domain name for the service.

**service.yml**

```
---
# declare front service
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-frontend-service
  namespace: traefik
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
    tier: reverse-proxy
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: NodePort
```

**ingress.yml**

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui-ingress
  namespace: traefik
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: "false"
    traefik.frontend.priority: "1"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: traefik-frontend-service.traefik.svc.cluster.local
              servicePort: 80
```

But I keep getting this error:

> The Ingress "traefik-web-ui-ingress" is invalid: spec.rules[0].http.backend.serviceName: Invalid value: "traefik-frontend-service.traefik.svc.cluster.local": a DNS-1035 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', start with an alphabetic character, and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'my-name',  or 'abc-123', regex used for validation is 'a-z?')

The service name of `traefik-frontend-service.traefik.svc.cluster.local`:

- starts with an alphanumeric character
- ends with an alphanumeric character
- only contains alphanumeric numbers or `-`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here... **unless a new ingress has to be created for each namespace**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design to avoid cross-namespace exposure, In this [thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17088) is explained why this limitation on the ingress specification was intentional.

That means, the **Ingress can only expose services within the same namespace**.

***The values provided should be the service name, not the FQDN.***

If you really need to design this way, your other alternatives are:

- Expose Traefik as a LB Service and then create a data service to provide the routing rules to traefik.
- Use [Contour Ingress (by heptio)](https://github.com/heptio/contour/blob/master/docs/ingressroute.md#across-namespaces) to delegate the routing to other namespaces.

  Using Contour would be something like this:

  ```
  # root.ingressroute.yaml
  apiVersion: contour.heptio.com/v1beta1
  kind: IngressRoute
  metadata:
    name: namespace-delegation-root
    namespace: default
  spec:
    virtualhost:
      fqdn: ns-root.bar.com
    routes:
      - match: /
        services:
          - name: s1
            port: 80
  # delegate the subpath, `/blog` to the IngressRoute object in the marketing namespace with the name `blog`
      - match: /blog
        delegate:
          name: blog
          namespace: marketing
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  # blog.ingressroute.yaml
  apiVersion: contour.heptio.com/v1beta1
  kind: IngressRoute
  metadata:
    name: blog
    namespace: marketing
  spec:
    routes:
      - match: /blog
        services:
          - name: s2
            port: 80
  ```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the intended behaviour. I will follow the best practice to separate the ingress for different namespaces. Is there a situation where you would use the FQDN for services though?

Comment: FQDN is mainly for services talking to each other within the cluster, because it only need a DNS and a Network(TCP/HTTP) to discover other services.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. Thanks! :D